# Include xml files as application files and not data files in ClickOnce

Tags: msbuild, clickonce

By default ClickOnce will include all .xml files as data files. This results in the xml files are deployed in a data directory and not in the application directory.

Is there a way to generate the manifest from MSBuild/Mage that will include xml files as application files viz., not add the writeable="applicationData" attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding the XML files to the project and within their properties change:

*[DELETED]*

**EDIT**: [Here's the information on changing the publish status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2(VS.80).aspx) of the file (with some modifications):

- With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu, click Properties.
- Click the **Publish** tab.
- Click the **Application Files** button to open the Application Files dialog box.
- In the **Application Files** dialog box, select the XML file.
- In the Publish Status field, select **Include** from the drop-down list.

Comment: The property is set to Copy always. The question is more about the deployment manifest and the attribute.

Comment: I believe I've found how to do it.  I've modified my answer to reflect the changes required.

Comment: Thanks, CAbbot. I found this question by searching and you solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just embed them as a resource in an assembly?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's two configuration files.